# Dax sum and weighted average in filtered data

Tags: filter, powerbi, reporting, dax, weighted-average

I'm trying to do a sum and a weighted average in DAX for Power Bi on filtered data. 
For example I've a table [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6UT5.png) and I need another column with the progressive sum of QUANTITA. This quantity must change based on the period of date filtered. I want also another calculated column with weighted-average.
Can anyone help me?

Tnx in advice.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the results you are expecting with the 2 calculated columns (progressive sum of QUANTITA and weighted-average)?